# What is the different between consume and delegate template quoted from WinRT header?

Tags: c++, templates, windows-runtime, c++14, msdn

Why is a `struct consume` defined without using template type?
What is the difference between `consume_t` and `delegate_t`?

```
template <typename T>
struct consume;

template <typename D, typename I = D>
using consume_t = typename consume<I>::template type<D>;

template <typename T>
struct delegate;

template <typename T, typename H>
using delegate_t = typename delegate<T>::template type<H>;
```

Comment: The second half of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: You should ask the person who wrote it. A shame they did not leave any documenting comments.

Comment: Is this from the Windows runtime? Did you get it from MSDN? Trying to determine the relevance of your tags but it's hard as you gave no context for this question.

Comment: I do not see a definition of `struct consume` (with or without a template type). I only see a declaration.

Comment: The difference between consume_t and delegate_t is that one is based on consume and one on delegate. Both are defined elsewhere and could be very different.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right, it is quoted from WinSDK cppwinrt/winrt/base.h. Because I am having hard time recognizing this pattern therefore I associated it with ambiguous tags.

Comment: Your edit has really focused the question, i.e. turned it into a single one. Because I consider the second question mark to be a specification detail of what puzzles you about the first one. Good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shown code does not contain a definition of `struct consume`, neither with nor without a template type.

This however is a (forward) declaration of it

```
template <typename T>
struct consume;
```

It only states that such a type does exist and that it takes a template parameter.

Same for `struct delegate`.

So it is clear that both exist, but the definition (elsewhere) is probably different.

That in turn means that `delegate_t` and `consume_t` are based on different templated types and hence also are (most probably) different, even though they seem to be so similarily defined.

Comment: The source is from the standard WinSDK path, for example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\base.h

Would you please help to quote the path of "struct consume" definition?

I could find other dependent types inherited from consume, for example "struct require_one"

Comment: Could you instead use a tool which searches your drive for that? The unix tool grep comes to mind, there are windows versions of that. Otherwise consider making a separate question please, because I consider this one answered. Finding the definition is a new one.

Comment: I have rephrased the question a bit, but still I could not find the definition of the consumer/delegate template using my tools, too many dependent types inherited from these two templates. Thanks for the linked resource,  it is very helpful.

Comment: I need to know the difference between these two forward declared types, maybe someone could find the actual interface/type declaration.

Comment: Be careful with editing questions after they got answers. People do not like "moving target questions". In this case however, the edited question actually fits better to the major part of my answer, so that is fine, don't worry. And thanks for the accept. That is good style.

Comment: Concerning what you still need to know: Please make another, separate question about that. Link to this one for background if you like.